# How can I remove non-English characters from column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem with my dataset. The column headers are written in both Arabic and English. I want to remove the Arabic language from the column headers. How would I do so?

Below is a snapshot of the column names.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Possible Solution: Iterate through the characters and replace with '' if it's not an English Alphabet. Also, include the code which you have tried and that causes error

Comment: I used this code:

batch_two.columns = [column.replace("ا", "") for column in batch_two.columns]

But should I use it per each character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `str.replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7f]_?', r'', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
# Before
>>> df.columns
Index(['on_col_اس_LOC01', 'another_col_رأس_LOC02'], dtype='object')

# After
>>> df.columns
Index(['on_col_LOC01', 'another_col_LOC02'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: If you provide the output of `print(df.columns)` it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For non-English character, using the `isascii()` function in Python

Then complete solution to your issue is:

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['arab', 'eng', 'vietnam'],
                   'val':['English then 1991 ا ف_جي2 ', 'English full', 'English then ế']})

df
      name                         val
0     arab  English then 1991 ا ف_جي2 
1      eng                English full
2  vietnam              English then ế
```

Remove non-English

```
df['cha_list'] = df['val'].str.split()
df['eng_only'] = df['cha_list'].apply(lambda g: [x for x in g if x.isascii()])
```

Result

```
      name                         val                         cha_list  \
0     arab  English then 1991 ا ف_جي2   [English, then, 1991, ا, ف_جي2]   
1      eng                English full                  [English, full]   
2  vietnam              English then ế               [English, then, ế]   

                eng_only  
0  [English, then, 1991]  
1        [English, full]  
2        [English, then]
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but I think the author want to remove from headers not for a column

Comment: you are correct, the logic is the same. I guess the author can figure it out

Comment: Thank you a lot. I actually would try it out on the other column values I have.